# fortran subroutine import in python fails

Tags: python, linux, fortran, python-import, f2py

I am trying to import a fortran subroutine into python code. Following this guide https://notmatthancock.github.io/2017/02/10/calling-fortran-from-python.html I have added the following line into my fortran code:

```
!f2py intent(in) :: ear,ne,parames,ifl
!f2py intent(out) photar,photer
```

However when I try to use `f2py -c fireball_ES_param.f -m fireball` to create fireball.so to import in my python code I get several hundreds of warnings, which might be the problem but I am not sure: https://www.4shared.com/s/f2ynHZ_Wjda (it's too long to be posted here).

In any case, the `fireball.cpython-34m.so` file gets created, but when I try to import that from python I get:

```
$ python

Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 13 2018, 12:45:42)  [GCC 4.8.4] on
linux2 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more
information.
>>> import fireball Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> ImportError:
  No module named fireball
```

I tried:

```
import sys

sys.path.append('/path/to/folder/containing/fireball.cpython-34m.so')
```

but got the same result. I am not sure if there is a problem with the creation of `fireball.so`, or with its `import`.

Comment: First comment: f2py uses Python 3.4 (as can be seen from the filename of the module) while you try tro import it in Python 2.7

Comment: One solution: import the code in Python 3.4 instead of Python 2.7. Other solution: see if you have f2py also for Python 2.7

Comment: sadly, using 3.4 did not bring any difference

Comment: where is the `.so` file located?

Comment: in the same folder where I start python, I also manually include the folder into the paths searched by python with `sys.path.append('/path/to/folder/containing/fireball.cpython-34m.so')`, but nothing changes

Comment: Appending the path is unnecessary.

Comment: What is the result of the command `python3 --version` and of `python3 -c 'import sys ; print(sys.path)'` and of `which python3`?

Comment: here is is:
`python3 --version`
`Python 3.6.3`
`$ python3 -c 'import sys ; print(sys.path)'`
`['', '/home/simone/root/lib', '/home/simone/heasoft-6.25/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-libc2.19/lib/python', '/home/simone/heasoft-6.25/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-libc2.19/lib', '/home/simone/heasoft-6.24/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-libc2.19/lib/python', '/home/simone/heasoft-6.24/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-libc2.19/lib', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']`
`$ which python3`
`/usr/bin/python3`

Comment: The OP appears to have at least 3 different Python versions (2.7, 3.4, 3.6), and the `f2py` command does not seem to be related to the `python` that is importing the module (what is the output of `which f2py`?). Assuming that whichever Python version being used has Numpy available, could some confusion not be avoided by issuing the f2py compilation as: `python[3] -m numpy.f2py -c fireball_ES_param.f -m fireball` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

f2py links to Python 3.4 (hence the 34 in `fireball.cpython-34m.so`) but python3 is actually version 3.6 (see you last comment).

Your options:

- Start your program with Python 3.4 which should be available as python3.4
- Update f2py to Python 3.6. If you installed via pip, `pip install --user -U numpy` should do. Then rebuild the extension.